# Writing out PointM shapefiles from QGIS

Tags: qgis, linear-referencing

I have a PointZM shapefile and I would like to drop the Z value and just write out the PointM values to a new shapefile (I'm trying to test a shapefile reader so other formats are not an option).

If I specify the geometry in the export window and uncheck `include z-dimension` I get a simple POINT file with just X & Y. If I check that box I get a POINTZ file with X, Y & Z.

Is there some trick I can use or should I file an enhancement request?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use "Processing Toolbox > Vector Geometry > **Drop M/Z Values**" tool.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As workaround, you could use a `virtual layer`, specifying a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT id, MakePointM(x, y, attribute) AS geometry FROM PointZM_layer;
```

And then export the `virtual layer` as a shapefile.

Please note: I didn't have the chance to test this! :)

Reference: https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/virtual_layers.html